# How can the components of a force be larger than the force itself?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

[image: 1]

Using this image - the triangle in particular as an eg, if the force no the feet against the machine was 100 N, then when I work out the vertical and horisontal components of the force I get answers that when added, exceed 100 N. Vertical 40.6 N and horisontal 91.4 N. I think that these are correct but my question is really about how is it possible that the components of a total 100 N force can be greater than 100 - by quite a lot.
Thanks for any replies, Im doing biomechanics and have a little maths ability and am interested in physics but this just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Neither 40 nor 91 are greater than 100, so what is your question?

Comment: You can't just add the other two orthogonal components and compare it against the vector sum. It's meaningless. Almost like adding applies and oranges.

Comment: Not being even a beginner with physics, I thought the two force components, being perpendicular to each other would add up to the 100N applied through the feet. It just seemed the intuitive - but obviously wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand where you are confused. Forces are vectors and add like vectors. In 2 dimensions we can split forces into 2 perpendicular components, so that adding the perpendicular components is like finding the hypotenuse of a right angle triangle.

You show in your question that you understand this:

$$(100 \text{N})^2= |\vec{F_{tot}}|^2 = |\vec{F_{x}}|^2+|\vec{F_{y}}|^2=(91.4 \text{N})^2+(40.6 \text{N})^2$$

This is all totally fine if you accept Pythagoras' Theorem. Not to mention by the triangle inequality the sum of the components of the force must always be greater than or equal to the total force.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.